# Issue with custom rake task in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am trying to create a Rake task that will send an email when a listing has not been updated in a month, but can't seem to get it to work.

I think the issue could be that I am trying to pull out the listing_agent email, but I have listing_agent_id in there.

update_listing_mailer.rb:

```
class UpdateListingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Help <help@realestate.com>"

  def listing_update_agent(agent)
    @agent = agent
    @listing = listing
    mail to: "#{agent.email}", subject: "Your listing hasn't been updated in a month!"
  end
end
```

listing_update_agent.html.erb:

```
Hiya, <br><br>

The listings below have not been updated in a month! Is it still on the market? If so, please update. If not, please remove from the market.<br><br>

<strong>Address:</strong> <%= @listing.address %>
<strong>Last Updated:</strong> <%= @listing.updated_at %>
<br><br>

Thanks,<br>
Management
```

listing_needs_update.rake:

```
namespace :listings do
  desc "Sends an email to the listing agent when that listing hasn't been updated in a month"
  task listing_update_agent: :enviroment do
    Listing.all.each do |listing|
      if listing.updated_at == Date.today - 30
        UpdateListingMailer.listing_update_agent(listing.listing_agent_id).deliver_now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

error:

[image]

trace:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an error, or explain in more detail what you mean "not working"?

Comment: @maxple I have added the errors.

Comment: Isn't your task named listing_update_agent, meaning that you should invoke it as rake listings:listing_update_agent??? Where did listing_needs_update come from? Would be much more clear and efficient if you could create an scope on Listing, something like Listing.not_updated_in_last_month so you don't have to ask for every Listing record if it's older than a month or not. You directly work with the records that need to be processed.

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo Wow...I feel stupid. It was the filename...it's been a long day! Could you elaborate on your suggestion to create a scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer here to make it more clear.

Your task is named listing_update_agent, meaning that you should invoke it as:

```
rake listings:listing_update_agent
```

Rather than:

```
rake listings:listing_needs_update
```

I can also think on some improvements on your code:

1) Task do things, so it'd be more semantic to call your task something like *notify_outdated_listings*

2) It'd be much more efficient to fetch the listings that need to be notified and work only with those, rather than asking for each record in the table, like you're doing in the task.
You can achieve this by creating a scope in the Listing model like:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_updated_in_last_month, -> { where('updated_at >= ?', 1.month.ago) } 
end
```

Then in your task:

```
namespace :listings do
  desc "Sends an email to the listing agent when that listing hasn't been updated in a month"
  task listing_update_agent: :enviroment do
    Listing.not_updated_in_last_month.each do |listing|
      UpdateListingMailer.listing_update_agent(listing.listing_agent_id).deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

Can you tell the difference in performance this change could make?

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up the syntax in the rush. Check the answer now.

Comment: No worries. I am worried that the listing_agent_id is not getting me the email address for that agent. Any insight into that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, listing_agent_id is an association field meaning that a Listing belongs to a ListingAgent? or is it just a random field with the name listing_agent_id?

Comment: There is a listing table and an agent table. In the listing table there is a listing_agent_id column which corresponds to the agent table.

Comment: So it's an association field. Can't you access the email in the task as: UpdateListingMailer.listing_update_agent(listing.listing_agent.email).deliver_now (or whatever the email column is named) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132349/discussion-between-mike-wiesenhart-and-dario-barrionuevo).